# Connecting peripherals to MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm moving from an older iMac to a new MacBook Pro. But I also want to be able to use a desk top moniter for detailed photo editing back at the office. In addition, I also want to be able to connect the MBP with two external drives. One of the drives serves as my backup "Time Machine" and the other is for safe storage of digital photo libraries.
Can this be done? And what do I need in terms of cables, adapters and/or hubs to do all this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of 'hub'. It is, unfortunately, the new normal.

You can just google 'macbook hub' to see hundreds of possibles, from $£€ 40 to $£€ 250 & more. It all depends on whether you need to just do a bit of USB or full display connectivity.